# loop break not working inside switch block on array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, switch-statement

Please refer the below code in which loop break does not work inside the switch block, can you help?

```
    String Books[] = { "Harry Potter", "To Kill a Mocking Bird", "Hunger Games" };

    //For loop is not breaking after getting the correct value
    for (int t = 0; t < Books.length; t++) {
      switch (Books[t]) {
        case "Harry Potter":
             System.out.println("Getting from switch case " + t + " " + Books[t]);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid search for book from switch case");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: The solution of using return works as long as you are returning the value found, if the method where the loop is returns void there will be no difference between found and not found, you will need to put extra checks in place, like checking a found flag or for !=null

Comment: You only break `switch` not `for`

Answer (score 3):

**`break` when used inside the `switch` statement breaks ONLY the switch flow, but not the for loop**, so
If you wanted to break the `for` loop, use `return` when the correct value is found which will `break` the loop and returns from the method, as shown below:

```
String Books[] = { "Harry Potter", "To Kill a Mocking Bird", "Hunger Games" };
    for (int t = 0; t < Books.length; t++) {
      switch (Books[t]) {
        case "Harry Potter":
             System.out.println("Getting from switch case " + t + " " + Books[t]);
            return;//use return when CORRECT CONDITION is found
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid search for book from switch case");
            break;
        }
    }
```

In simple terms, your `break` will be applied to the inner code block which is a `switch` here, so it doesn't `break` the `for` loop. So, if you wanted to `break` both `switch` & `for` together, use `return` statement so that it returns from the method.

One important point is that **do not use the labels (to jump between lines)** in the code which is **against to the structured programming**.

**OPTION(2):**

If you don't want to `return` from the method, you need to refactor your code and move the book finding logic to a separate method like `checkBookExists` as shown below:

```
private boolean checkBookExists(String book, int t) {
      boolean bookFound = false;
      switch (book) {
        case "Harry Potter":
            bookFound = true;
            System.out.println("Getting from switch case " + t + " " + book);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid search for book from switch case");
            break;
        }
        return bookFound;
   }
```

Now call that `checkBookExists` method inside the `for` loop as shown below and when the book is found, `for` will `break`.

```
String Books[] = { "Harry Potter", "To Kill a Mocking Bird", "Hunger Games" };
    for (int t = 0; t < Books.length; t++) {
        if(checkBookExists(Books[t], t)) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! This is also great

Comment: I recommend either of these options than labels, which are bad practice, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133127/why-it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-break-continue-labels-in-oop-e-g-java-c

Comment: Nice solution , if you find his solution useful accept it to be as reference in the future

Comment: @javaguy i like this point " do not use the labels (to jump between lines) in the code which is against to the structured programming."

important note and you are right jump label is preferred to use only with low level languages like assembly and it's necessary to work with  it in low level programming.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that break will only break out of the switch statement. You can try using a [labeled break](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html), e.g.

```
loop:
for (int t = 0; t < Books.length; t++ ) {
    // ...
    case:
        // ...
        break loop;
```

Or, you could put the loop in its own method instead and use a return statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked :)